# How do I access the reflow mode on Adobe Reader?

Tags: pdf, ebook-reader, adobe-reader, reading

How do I access the reflow mode on Adobe Reader for Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At Adobe Reader click on top part of screen, then you will see top toolbar. At toolbar you need 4 button from right corner of toolbar.